# R 4.0 can't compile C sources in MacOs Catalina, clang-7 error

Tags: c++, r, macos, compiler-errors, updates

Since I updated R to v4.0 the C compiler seems broken. This is the culprit error (I think):

```
clang-7: error: no such file or directory: '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libc++abi.1.dylib'
```

I look around on the internet but no solution seems to work.

I'm on MacOS 10.15.3.

Comment: Have you tried this guide: https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/

Comment: I think the problem were some clang statements in .Renviron and .R/Makevars. I don't know where did they came from

Comment: I had the exact same issue and was driving me nuts until I found this. The Makevars file was referencing old clang installs that had since been deleted. Deleting both files worked like a charm, thanks!!